Why doesn't transition work on <aside> to smoothly adjust width when hovered?
I'm trying to create a layout where an aside element smoothly increases its width when hovered.
The grid is set up using grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr, and I expect the aside element to expand to match its content (max-content) with a smooth transition. However, the transition doesn't seem to work as expected.
To simplify my use case:
Initially, the aside only shows icons. I want it to display icons with text when hovered, and the width of aside should increase smoothly during the hover state.
The .text-box is a p element that is a child of aside and a sibling of the icon *(image). By default, the .text-box is set to display: none, and it becomes visible (display: block) when the aside is hovered.
Here is the CSS code:
.grid-con {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
grid-auto-flow: auto;
grid-template-areas:
    "aside main"
    "aside main"
    "footer footer";
min-height: 100vh;

}
aside {
grid-area: aside;
border-radius: 20px;
padding: var(--sp-xm);
background-color: #fff;
transition: all 0.5s linear;

}
aside .text-box {
display: none;

}
aside: hover .text-box {
display: block;

}

It will be helpful to understand and work if there is a minimal, reproduceable example.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Note that you trying (effectively) to transition from max-content to max-content (which you obviously you cannot do). The width of the aside is in fact (I suggest) auto and, as yet, you cannot transition that either. Regardless, the real issue is that you pop the text in from nothing and expect it to transition which, again, you cannot do. I suggest you find another method to expand the text from zero to it's 100%. A clip-path perhaps?
